# Association with FactoryGirl throws undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got an activity which belongs to many activities. Whenever I test my factory with rSpec I get an error.

My **Test** is:

```
it "has valid factory" do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:activity)).to be_valid
end
```

And the **error** given is:

```
  1) Activity has valid factory
     Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:activity)).to be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `client=' for #<Activity:0x6cbb800>
     # C:in `object'
     # ./spec/models/activity_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

It's been like this since I've added `association :client` to my **activities factory**:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :activity do
        title "Activity"
        start_date {Date.parse('2013-05-13 12:00:00')}
        end_date {Date.parse('2013-05-13 12:15:00')}
        pictogram_id "1"
        association :client
    end
end
```

And the client on itself passes all tests aswell. With the same factory: (**clients.rb**)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :client do
        name "Client name"
        background "#FFFFFF"
        birthdate {15.years.ago}
    end
end
```

Since it's not a test DB prepare/clone problem I'm updating the post with the relevant part of my **schema.rb**

```
  create_table "activities", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.integer  "pictogram_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "activities", ["pictogram_id"], name: "index_activities_on_pictogram_id"

  create_table "activities_clients", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "activity_id"
    t.integer "client_id"
  end

  add_index "activities_clients", ["activity_id"], name: "index_activities_clients_on_activity_id"
  add_index "activities_clients", ["client_id"], name: "index_activities_clients_on_client_id"

  create_table "clients", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.date     "birthdate"
    t.string   "background"
    t.integer  "group_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Any idea why the association fails to ehm.. associate?

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens if you have a database schema change that hasn't been run on your test database. Make sure you run "rake db:test:prepare" after a recent migration.

Comment: That was my thought too. Cloning didn't work either. I've editted my post with my schema.rb

Comment: It looks like you're getting has_many and has_and_belongs_to_many confused. Your database is setup for the latter, but you're trying to use it as a has_many relationship where an activity can only belong to a single client. Which is it?

Comment: Ehm. No; editting this comment: It should be has_many in my DB. How do I fix that? >_<

Comment: Get rid of the activities_clients table and add a client_id foreign key to the clients table.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I'm rather new to this :)

Comment: I would check out this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks! It feels weird to add a client_id foreign key to the client. Did you mean activity_id to the client?

Comment: yup! I did mean that.

Comment: I'm fooling around a little now. I think the best way is to add a ´references :client´ to my activities table and use ´has_many` in activity.rb and `belongs_to` in client.rb. Is this correct?